# Regex: cutting a portion of string between two characters (for smarty)

Tags: regex, string, replace, smarty, cut

I need to cut a portion of a string delimited by two characters. 
(From the second ":" to the "|")

EG, I have this string (without quotation marks):
"Materiale : Pelle naturale, Colore : Pelle | Rosso"

and I must remove " Pelle | " in the results.
Note that "Pelle" is just an example, but it could be a lot of different words.

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Try `{'/((?:[^:]+:){2})[^|]+\|/'|preg_replace:'$1':$value}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why not `:([^:]*\|)` ?

Comment: @Thomas: Then, you can match more than is expected.

Comment: Thank you, guys.
WiktorStribiżew's tip worked like a charm :)

Comment: Glad to help, but please add what you tried to the question, OK? I will write my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
{'/((?:[^:]+:){2})[^|]+\|/'|preg_replace:'$1':$value}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK1lO5/1)

The regex means:

- `((?:[^:]+:){2})` - matches and captures into Group 1 two sequences of:

  - `[^:]+` - 1+ symbols other than `:`
  - `:` - a literal `:`
- `[^|]+\|` - 1+ characters other than `|` (with `[^|]+`) and then `|`.

In the replacement pattern, we just restore the Group 1 with the `$1` backreference that gets the text captured by the first group.

The [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) is a very handy construct in regex.